# is there a shorter regex for this pattern

Tags: python, regex

To find out which submitted SQL queries end with a LIMIT clause, I'm using the following regex:

```
re_end_has_limit = re.compile(
    r'LIMIT\s+(\d+|\(\d+\)|\(\s+\d+\)|\(\s+\d+\s+\))($|;$|\s+;$|\s+;\s+$)', 
    re.IGNORECASE)
```

This matches the following & works as intended. It matches the following:

```
LIMIT 1
LIMIT (1)
LIMIT ( 1 )
LIMIT 1;
LIMIT (1);
LIMIT ( 1 );
LIMIT 1 ;
LIMIT (1) ;
LIMIT ( 1 ) ;
LIMIT 1 ; 
LIMIT (1) ; 
LIMIT ( 1 ) ;
```

**Note**: The last 3 entries contain a trailing space character.

However, looking at the regex, I feel like there's a way to write it shorter but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: You might want to learn about `*` and `?`. Also, your regex doesn't match `LIMIT(1)`.

Comment: thanks, after learning about `*`, I got `pattern = r'LIMIT(\s+\d+|\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\))\s*(;\s*$|$)'`, and after learning about `?` I reached the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
LIMIT(\s+\d+|\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\))\s*;?\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also an option:

```
LIMIT\s*(\()?\s*\d+\s*(?(1)\))\s*;?\s*$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BuELvV/2)

Instead of using or(`|`), like the accepted answer does, it uses if(`(?(1)...)`.

Answer (score -1):

I am unfamiliar with SQL queries but looking at your examples I think this should work to find all LIMIT clauses:

```
re_end_has_limit = re.compile(r'LIMIT[ \(]+\d', re.g)
```

Comment: @melpomene: I have corrected the answer to not match your new example.

Comment: Matches `SELECT 'the SKY is the LIMIT (1 2 3)' FROM DUAL`.

Comment: I give up... These kinds of limitations were not obvious from the original question! Also the other answers do not work either when trying them on regex101...